# Is there an open source html menu component like Trello's?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I really like the menu system of Trello where sub-menus appear over the top of the previous menu with a back button. This is great for smaller screen sizes, or deeper menu structures. Can anyone suggest an open source component that has similar functionality, or a better way of dealing with sub-menus on smaller screen sizes, especially now sub-menus will be removed from the next release of Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This would be what you're looking for:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Comment: This link is broken, but the jquery-mobile menu uses an accordion so is quite different from the menus in Trello. Accordion menus could be a good options though.

Comment: Just checked the link, it is not broken, it might have been a temporary issue.

It is not an accordion menu, I haven't used Trello but from what I can see in the screenshots of the app, this is pretty much the same.